# How to compare two two digit integers as is, reversed, and one character at a time

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, integer, logic

I am new to programming and am trying to learn it by taking an intro class using python.

One of my assignments requires us to do the following:

1. compare a randomly generated two digit integer with a user generated two digit integer.

   1. if both the random and user generated integers match print blah1
   2. if the user generated integer has the same two digits as the random generated integer in reverse, print blah2
   3. if the user generated integer has one digit that is the same as the randomly generated integer, print blah3.

Now, so far, we have only learned the basic stuff, (operators, `if`/`else`/`elif`, `while` loops, printing, strings, integers)

I came up with something that randomly assigns two digits, converts them into strings, and then concatenates them into a two digit string. From here, I used `elif` statements to match each possible condition.

Unfortunately, that's not what's required.  I must use two digit integers when I do my comparisons. Unfortunately, I have absolutely no clue how to compare portions of an integer, or reverse the integer with what I've been taught.

Now, I am not looking for someone to solve this for me.  I want some help, either a hint or a suggestion on how I should think about this with the basic knowledge I have.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

I've included the code that I wrote.

```
# homework 2
# problem 1
#
# lottery guessing program
#
# the program randomly generates a two-digit number, prompts the user to enter a two-digit number,
# and determines whether the user wins according to the following rules:
#
# 1. if both digits match in the right order, you will win $10,000.
# 2. if both digits match, but in the reversed order, you will win $3,000.
# 3. if you match one digit in either place, you will win $1,000

#imports
import random

#rules
print("guess a number.  if both digits match in the right order, you will win $10,000."\
      "\nif both digits match, but in the reversed order, you will win $3,000." \
      "\nif you match one digit in either place, you will win $1,000." \
      "\nif you don't match any digits, you do not win anything.")

# random variables
rand_num1 = str(random.randint(1,9))
rand_num2 = str(random.randint(1,9))

#ask user for number
user_num1 = input("what is your first number? ")
user_num2 = input("what is your second number? ")

#for testing purposes, if testing, comment out the previous two lines
#combd_num = (str(rand_num1)) + (str(rand_num2))
#revsd_num = (str(rand_num2)) + (str(rand_num1))
#print(rand_num1)
#print(rand_num2)
#print(combd_num)
#print(revsd_num)
#user_num1 = input("what is your first number? ")
#user_num2 = input("what is your second number? ")
#ucomb_num = (str(user_num1)) + (str(user_num2))

#output the numbers
print("the number is, ", (rand_num1 + rand_num2),"\
      \nyour number is, ", (user_num1 + user_num2), sep="")

#elif statement
if (user_num1 + user_num2) == (rand_num1 + rand_num2):
    print("you guessed the exact number.  you win $10,000!")
elif (user_num2 + user_num1) == (rand_num1 + rand_num2):
    print("you guessed both digits but in reverse.  you win $3,000!")
elif user_num1 == rand_num1 and user_num2 != rand_num2:
    print("you guessed one digit right.  you win $1,000!")
elif user_num1 == rand_num2 and user_num2 != rand_num2:
    print("you guessed one digit right.  you win $1,000!")
elif user_num2 == rand_num1 and user_num1 != rand_num2:
    print("you guessed one digit right.  you win $1,000!")
elif user_num2 == rand_num2 and user_num1 != rand_num2:
    print("you guessed one digit right.  you win $1,000!")
else:
    print("sorry, you didn't guess the right number.")
```

Answer (score 4):

There are three tricks that'll help you here:

1. Lists can be compared just like strings and numbers. A list of integers can be compared to another and if the contained numbers are the same, the comparison returns `True`:

   ```
   >>> [1, 2] == [1, 2]
   True
   >>> [1, 3] == [1, 2]
   False
   ```
2. You can *reverse* a list easily. You can use the `reversed()` built-in function, or you can use the `[start:stop:stride]` slice notation to give a *negative* stride. The latter gives you a reversed list too:

   ```
   >>> list(reversed([1, 2]))
   [2, 1]
   >>> [1, 2][::-1]
   [2, 1]
   ```

   The `reversed()` function returns an iterator, by passing that to the `list()` constructor we get a list again.
3. You can use the `in` operator to test list membership. Use this to test if an individual integer is part of a list of integers:

   ```
   >>> 1 in [1, 2]
   True
   >>> 3 in [1, 2]
   False
   ```

These 3 tricks together should give you all the tools you need to re-program your script to work with integers. Store both your random numbers and the user input (turned to integers with the `int()` function) in lists and work your way from there.

If you *must* accept *one* integer input between 10 and 99 things get a little trickier. You can separate out the 10s and the 1s by using th modulo `%` and division `\` operators:

```
ones = number % 10
tens = number // 10
```

You can combine the two operations using the [`divmod()` function](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
tens, ones = divmod(number, 10)
```

Now you have two separate integers again to do your comparisons with.

Comment: Sameer might also find it helpful to know that the obvious `[1,2]==reversed([2,1])` gives `False`, you have to use `[1,2]==list(reversed([2,1]))` or the slicing notation to get a list for comparison. BTW, I don't believe your output for the example you gave using `reversed()`.

Comment: Right, in Python 3, reversed is an iterator, I am using Python 2 too often still. I'll correct.

Comment: Doesn't `reversed` return a `listreverseiterator object` in Python 2 as well?

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  i don't know why i didn't notice the integer division and modulus operators before.  thanks, that pretty much did it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the challenge you're facing is how to get the separate digits from a two digit integer. It is possible to do using mathematical operators.

Just think about what each digit in a number like `42` represents. The `4` is the "tens" digit and the 2 is the "ones" digit. It might help to think about it in reverse. If you have the integers `4` and a `2` in separate variables, how would you assemble them into the single integer `42`?

Hopefully my hints will help you out! If I've been too oblique, I can try to elaborate a bit more, but I do want you to be able to solve it on your own, and I suspect you'll get it quickly once you've thought of the right operators to use.

Answer (score 0):

alright, thanks to everyone's help.  because of your suggestions and hints, i managed to complete the assignment according to specs.

while, i am not too proud of how it was done - just seems sloppy to me - it works.

here it is:

```
#imports
import random

#rules
print("guess a number.  if both digits match in the right order, you will win $10,000."\
      "\nif both digits match, but in the reversed order, you will win $3,000." \
      "\nif you match one digit in either place, you will win $1,000." \
      "\nif you don't match any digits, you do not win anything.")

#random variable
rand_num = random.randint(0,99)
print(rand_num)
#separate the digits
rand_num_tens = rand_num//10
print(rand_num_tens)
rand_num_ones = rand_num%10
print(rand_num_ones)
#reverse the random number digits
revsd_rnd_num = (rand_num_ones * 10) + rand_num_tens
print(revsd_rnd_num)

#ask user for number
user_num = int(input("guess a number between 1 and 99: "))
#separate the digits
user_num_tens = user_num//10
print(user_num_tens)
user_num_ones = user_num%10
print(user_num_ones)

#output the numbers
print("the number is, ", rand_num,"\
      \nyour number is, ", user_num, sep="")

#elif statement
if rand_num == user_num:
    print("you guessed the exact number.  you win $10,000!")
elif revsd_rnd_num == user_num:
    print("you guessed both digits but in reverse.  you win $3,000!")
elif rand_num_tens == user_num_tens:
    print("you guessed one digit right.  you win $1,000!")
elif rand_num_tens == user_num_ones:
    print("you guessed one digit right.  you win $1,000!")
elif rand_num_ones == user_num_tens:
    print("you guessed one digit right.  you win $1,000!")
elif rand_num_ones == user_num_ones:
    print("you guessed one digit right.  you win $1,000!")
else:
    print("sorry, you didn't guess the right number.")
```